# Select top 2 row of each item in multi index data frame in pandas

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have multi-index dataframe and I want to select the top 2 rows from every item in level 1.  This is not the dataframe but as an example >> say this data frame

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
list('aaabbbcccddd'),
list('tuvwacdjpkqz')
], names=['level 1', 'level 2'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(len(mux))}, mux)
```

I would want the following OUTPUT you get from running this data frame.  So the first 2 items from each entry at level 1.  These are just example of the output >> i dont want to re-create the dataframe but rather select first two rows from the first one

```
emux2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
list('aabbccdd'),
list('tuwadjkq')], names=['level 1', 'level 2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(len(mux2))}, mux2)
```

How can I slice data frame df to get these results in df2?

Comment: your expected output doesnt match the input dataframe... example level = a should have 0 and 1 ? do you want `df.groupby(level=0).head(2)` ?

Comment: Yes, ty.  this is what I wanted